# Time Complexity of using the kernel trick on polynomial basis expansion

Tags: machine-learning, svm, kernel-trick, time-complexity

I have read that:

If we have two feature vectors ${x = (x_1,x_2,…,x_D)}$ and $y=(y_1,y_2,…,y_D)$ and we do a degree d polynomial basis expansion to get $f(x)$ and $f(y)$, then to calculate the inner product $f(x)^Tf(y)$ requires time roughly $D^d$.

However with the kernel trick we have a polynomial kernel to where $f(x)^Tf(y) = k(x,y) = (1+x^Ty)^d$.

It then says that this kernel trick only takes time $O(D\text{log}_d)$& and I don’t understand where this comes from.